Bullets points are not function properly in rich text in salesforce
When we use bullet points in the Salesforce Standard Rich Text area field, we notice that the functionality of bullet points is not working correctly. For example, when we use the first bullet and add a child bullet as "a", the child bullet of the second point should start with "a" as well. However, instead of "a", it shows "b".
Below are the images for reference.
enter image description here
The expectation is that child bullet points should start from the beginning.
